# C# Regex: Checking for "a-z" and "A-Z"

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if a string inputted in a character between a-z or A-Z. Somehow my regular expression doesn't seem to pick it up. It always returns true. I am not sure why, I gather it has to do with how I am writing my regular expression. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private static bool isValid(String str)
{
    bool valid = false;

    Regex reg = new Regex((@"a-zA-Z+"));

    if (reg.Match(str).Success)
        valid = false;
    else 
        valid  = true;     

     return valid;
}
```

Comment: You're setting it to false after it matches.

Comment: A TIP: Rather than writing `a-zA-Z` you can use `?i` to make your regex pattern case insensitive and then just write `a-z`where ever required.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The right way would be like so:

```
private static bool isValid(String str)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
}
```

This code has the following benefits:

- Using the static method instead of creating a new instance every time: The static method caches the regular expression
- Fixed the regex. It now matches any string that consists of one or more of the characters a-z or A-Z. No other characters are allowed.
- Much shorter and readable.

Comment: Because of the anchors ^ and $, ^[a-zA-Z]+$ will match a string if it is entirely composed of letters (probably what the OT intends, but you should update the explanation).

Answer (score 28):

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

- `^` start of the string
- `[]`  character set
- `\+` one time or the more
- `$` end of the string

`^` and `$` needed because you want validate all string, not part of the string

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
Regex.IsMatch(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update in .NET 7 (Nov 2022+)

There is a [new method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68868) called [`Char.IsAsciiLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciiletter?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.0) which will:

> determine whether the character is in the range 'A' through 'Z', inclusive, or 'a' through 'z', inclusive.

If you want to test that a string has ***any*** english letters, you can use [`Linq.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0)

```cs
var hasLetter = "word".Any(Char.IsAsciiLetter); // true
```

If you want to test that a string has ***only*** english letters, you can use [`Linq.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-7.0)

```cs
var allLetters = "word".All(Char.IsAsciiLetter); // true
```

#### Generated Regex Source Code

.NET 7 [Introduced GeneratedRegex](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/#source-generation) which allows you to parse and compile regex statements at compile time, but *also* allows you to *inspect any optimizations done under the hood*.  If you want to see how the regex string `[a-zA-Z]` is actually implemented, you can add the following to any dotnet 7 project

```cs
public static partial class RegexExtensions
{
    [GeneratedRegex("[a-zA-Z]")]
    public static partial Regex HasLetter();
}
```

And then view source on the generated code. You'll see that even if you use regex as performantly as possible, it'll just use the exact same method on the `char` class anyway under the hood:

[image: "[a-zA-Z]" regex source code]

#### Performance Benchmarks

According to [benchmark tests](https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/1781d304634c703e7f4a81782166af56), the fastest way to check if a string contains an english letter is to use a **for loop with `Char.IsAsciiLetter`**:

[image: Has a-z benchmarks]

### Polyfill

If you're not on .NET 7 yet, you can look at how the [method is implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/69318/files?w=1#diff-ea5ef93981b66b93a8906532bba87b7908ebf2042170b647a8953a9e952cbc06R236) for a performance-aware implementation:

```cs
public static bool IsAsciiLetter(char c) => (uint)((c | 0x20) - 'a') <= 'z' - 'a';
```