# How to check if a String contains any letter from a to z?

Tags: c#, windows, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Regex: Checking for “a-z” and “A-Z”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017778/c-sharp-regex-checking-for-a-z-and-a-z)

I could just use the code below:

```
String hello = "Hello1";
Char[] convertedString = String.ToCharArray();
int errorCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < CreateAccountPage_PasswordBox_Password.Password.Length; i++) {
    if (convertedString[i].Equals('a') || convertedString[i].Equals('A') .....
                            || convertedString[i].Equals('z') || convertedString[i].Equals('Z')) {
        errorCounter++;
    }
}
if(errorCounter > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

but I suppose it takes too much line for just a simple purpose, I believe there is a way which is much more simple, the way which I have not yet mastered.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question since it isn't strictly related to a regex.

Comment: I'd also argue that this isn't a duplicate. At least not of a duplicate of _C# Regex: Checking for “a-z” and “A-Z”_ since this question is asking wether a string contains any char a-zA-Z and the other question is asking of the string solely contains of a-zA-Z...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Replace your `for loop` by this :

```
errorCounter = Regex.Matches(yourstring,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count;
```

Remember to use `Regex` class, you have to `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` in your import

Comment: oh excuse me I got one more question, how to detect not only letters from a to z but also all symbols? like . , ! ? < > # $

Comment: Careful with this regex if you have to deal with non a-z letters (chinese, etc.)

Answer (score 115):

What about:

```
//true if it doesn't contain letters
bool result = hello.Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x));
```

Comment: Note: this checks if there are any characters that are not a letter, it does not check if a string has letters in it.
Simple fix:
bool result = !hello.Any(x => char.IsLetter(x));

Comment: I'm glad there's a LINQ answer here, so I don't have to use Regex.

Comment: Shouldn't `!hello.Any(char.IsLetter);` also work?

Comment: björn: That will return true if no character is a letter, which is not what was asked. In a somewhat related manner, the question was specifically for A-Z, a-z, althought that might not be what was really wanted.

Comment: If the string has a new line "\r" or "\n" then it will return true

Comment: char.IsLetter will match any unicode characters too. not just a-z in English.

Answer (score 27):

You could use RegEx:

```
Regex.IsMatch(hello, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

If you don't like that, you can use LINQ:

```
hello.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

Or, you can loop through the characters, and use isAlpha:

```
Char.IsLetter(character);
```

Comment: Im sorry but it reads only if I the entire String is number, if I put number and letter it won't detect

Comment: The correct regex would be

    `Regex.IsMatch(hello, @"[a-zA-Z]");`

Answer (score 7):

You can look for [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Comment: I can't believe you could make it so easy!

Comment: instead this can also be use: `(?i)^[a-z]+$`, Here `?i` makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

For a minimal change:

```
for(int i=0; i<str.Length; i++ )
   if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z' || str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
      errorCount++;
```

You could use regular expressions, at least if speed is not an issue and you do not really need the actual exact count.

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression
no need to convert it to char array

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("yourString",".*?[a-zA-Z].*?"))
{
errorCounter++;
}
```