# C# - make Regex detects any character that isn't digit

Tags: c#, regex

Previously on [How to check if a String contains any letter from a to z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884610/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letter-from-a-to-z#12884639) I have learnt how to use Regex to detect letters from `a` to `z`.

Can we make Regex to detect any symbols too? Like `. , ! ? @ # $ % ^ & * ( )` or any other else.

More specifically, I want to accept **only digits** in my `string`.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and sample output?

Comment: I'm making an if statement that it will only executed when the String contains only numbers

Comment: @Anggrian `c# in a nutshell` has very good info on regex..tht should help u get started!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match string containing only digits or empty string use regex pattern `^\d*$`

To match string containing only digits, not allowing an empty string use regex pattern `^\d+$`

```
Console.WriteLine((new Regex(@"^\d+$")).IsMatch(string) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/MZryl)**.

---

Learn more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

create regex number first

```
private Boolean number(string obj)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
            Match m = r.Match(obj);
            if (m.Success == true) return true;
            else { return false; }
        }
```

and make sure that is number

```
if (number(textBox1.Text) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("text box couldn't filled with numbers", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *faster-than-regex* and *easier-to-maintain* solution :

```
string num = "123456a";
bool isOnlyDigits = num.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: @Ωmega, So is this the only reason to download? Is "showing other alternatives" is a bad thing? Maybe OP doesn't know linq alternatives and may decide to use it.

Comment: I believe you should add some explanation to your code or offer regex solution as well, as without any note (as you posted just code), it certainly not what OP asked for. I will be more than happy to remove my downvote if you add some text and/or explanation to your non-regex solution, or if you offer regex solution. Fair enough?

Comment: @Ωmega , No I won't add an any explanation(which is clear enough) and regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `Regex` by just following certain conventions. Refer to this [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28WWrrbShGqsK-q9hDTTZWJDJyHaroOS2i0Srx9NzZ3GhmdgoAAfb61CQytP9pFb_9MVceuDA2rOJeX9ez8jNA2pLzAYiPnqaUwNaqH5paYlmfpBbMZEacZMP2gA3wsoh23T00U55TBJVTSVes197dQ_9KAgTzg60rX_I5n7UEWxTrhsXnzWhSaFvtGrygAnwH0%29%29/CheatSheet.aspx) to create your own Regex.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+` will match 1 or more digits.

For example:

```
var myString = @"fasd df @###4 dfdfkl  445jlkm  kkfd ## jdjfn ((3443  ";
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
var matches = regex.Match(myString); // This will match: 4, 445 and 3443
```

Hope this helps.