# Check string for characters, without getting hung up on spaces

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, string, integer

Currently, in my program I'm checking my strings to see if they are NOT of an integer value by using the following `Regex` method along with an `if` statement:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^\d+$") == false) {}
```

However, I need to allow values such as: "45 23 12". These values involve spaces, which I believe are counted as characters by `Regex` because whenever I try an example like the previous one, my code returns false.

**How do I perform a check for values that aren't integers while allowing the use of spaces?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884610/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-letter-from-a-to-z) uses `Regex.Matches(myString,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count` to check the string for all character occurrences from 'a-z', which doesn't involve " ". However, I notice when I use it in my `if`statement that it's of type Int, which can't be compared to `false` with `==`.

Comment: Dont put `Matches` in your if statement.  Change it to `IsMatch`

Comment: Is "45 23 12" supposed to be treated as a single integer?

Comment: @Malk No, they are individual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(! Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^\s*\d(\d|\s)*$")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the regex

```
^\d+(\s\d+)*$
```

Explanation:

```
^          beginning of line.
\d+        one or more digits.
(\s\d+)*   zero, one or more repetitions of space + one or more digits.
$          end of line.
```

```cs
if (!Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^\d+(\s\d+)*$")) {
    ...
}
```

---

And please write

`!<boolean expression>` instead of `<boolean expression> = false`.

and

`<Boolean expression>` instead of `<Boolean expression> = true`.

You don't write `1 * x` but simply `x`.

A lot of people think that if-statements require a comparison. They do not. What they require is a Boolean expression, i.e. an expression yielding a value of `true` or `false`. `Regex.IsMatch(...)` returns a `bool` value and this is all we need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex (if I understand your question correctly.

```
^(?:\d|\s)+$
```

It seems to do what you want and [here is the test for it](http://regex101.com/r/uB8lC8).