# How to check if string contains at least one alphabetical letter (a-z,A-Z) C#

Tags: c#, regex, contains

could someone telle me please how to check if a string contains at least one alphabetical letter?
I tryed:

```
if (StringName.Text.Contains(Char.IsLetter()))
{
 //Do Something
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
if (StringName.Text.Any(Char.IsLetter))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Very strange that no one come up with anything close to this answer before you... Maybe [another universe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884682/477420)...

Answer (score 3):

Try *Linq*. If you accept *any* Unicode letter, say, Russian `ъ`:

```
if (StringName.Text.Any(c => char.IsLetter(c))) 
{
    // Do Something
}
```

In case you want just `a..z` as well as `A..Z`:

```
if (StringName.Text.Any(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) 
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Finally, if you insist on *regular expressions*:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(StringName.Text, @"\p{L}")) 
{
   // Do Something 
}
```

Or (second option) `a..z` as well as `A..Z` letters only

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(StringName.Text, @"[a-zA-Z]")) 
{
   // Do Something 
}
```