# How to do format check on string?vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do check that a string only consists of letters?@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to check if a string contains only letters:

```
Dim text As String = "abcd"
Dim flag As Boolean = text.AsEnumerable().All(Function(c As Char) Char.IsLetter(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `String.Contains()` This exsplains how to use it, http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Contains.htm

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str As String
        str = "VB.NET TOP 10 BOOKS"
        If str.Contains("TOP") = True Then
            MsgBox("The string Contains() 'TOP' ")
        Else
            MsgBox("The String does not Contains() 'TOP'")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: I'm not sure why your post includes a lot of @'s, is it an example of the text your looking to check over? :3

```
Public Function isValid(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
    Dim reg As New Regex(pattern)
    Return reg.IsMatch(str)
End Function
```

This could possibly be the solution your after.

Comment: erm, im looking for something like str only consists of a to z letters,other than that i will set a variable to false,indicating that it is invalid string.

Comment: Updated my answer, The Regex would check against the allowed characters and return the outcome.

Comment: do u have any simpler coding?i mean use basic coding to do this.eg loop, string manipulation

Comment: Using loops or string manipulation as opposed to just using a function that returns if you're string contains all lower and upper case letters from A-Z in three line is already quite simple.

Comment: k nvm then, erm do u know how to format a telephone number so that it will have the format xx-xxxxxxx?

Comment: depending on the format you would have 3 value boxes and then a submit button, The submit button would concatenate the values in the three boxes and in between you would be able to add "-". Then using IF statements you can validate the user input programmatically.

Comment: my input is only once. So i have to perform validation on that input only.  do u know what is this String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Long.Parse(PhoneString))??<<saw it from other place, can i use this?

Comment: This is going woefully off topic now, but yes that would sound about right for parsing information off a string.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regular expression like in this question:

[C# Regex: Checking for "a-z" and "A-Z"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017778/c-sharp-regex-checking-for-a-z-and-a-z)

The vb should be very similar:

```
private function isValid(byval str as String) as Boolean

    return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")

End Function
```