# C# Program to check for valid values

Tags: c#

I need some help to remove duplicate values from the following program. I cannot use Hashset, list or anything except Arrays. I have looked at different solutions that i can use Hashset and list, but i am not allowed to use that. Can someone help me with this. The program is suppose to take only 5 values between a to j and remove any duplication values:

```
class Program
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] Array = new char[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only: ");
        string letters = "abcdefghij";
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length;)
        {
                string lower = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (letters.Contains(lower) && lower.Length == 1)
                {
                    Array[i] = Convert.ToChar(lower);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value);
                    continue;
                }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
        for (int i = 0; i<Array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're checking if the `letters` string contains the whole `lower` string. You should be going through the `lower` letter by letter.

Comment: use .ToUpper instead of .toLower, its better optimized according to microsoft.

Comment: You need to check if `lower` is also contained in the `char[] Array` before trying to add it to the array. Are you also forbidden to use `List<char>()`? Or, just append the given input characters to a normal `string` and call `thatString.Contains(..)`.

Comment: Yeah. that is the challenge. I am not suppose to use List<> or hashset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input with letters (a-z) only without special characters or numbers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191717/how-to-ask-for-user-input-with-letters-a-z-only-without-special-characters-or)

Comment: You've asked the same question 4 times in 2 days; please check the [StackOverflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on asking questions. [2 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191717), [1 day ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213210), [4 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239820), [1 hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241502)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
static void Main()
    {
        char[] array = new char[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only: ");
        string letters = "abcdefghij";

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < 5)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            char myChar = input[0];

            if (input.Length != 1 || array.Contains(myChar) || !letters.Contains(myChar))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
                continue;
            }

            array[counter++] = myChar;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
    }
```

Comment: For what i was looking for, this is the code works. I had to modify it slightly to give me different errors and other calculations but this works wonders. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] Array = new char[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only: ");
        string letters = "abcdefghij";

        char[] read = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray();

        //loop through array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (letters.Contains(read[i]) && !Array.Contains(read[i]))
            {
                Array[i] = read[i];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

That code should do what you want

Comment: I am getting an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in OneDimensionalArray.exe" in the section                                                                                                                                                 if (letters.Contains(read[i]) && !Array.Contains(read[i]))

Comment: did you enter 5 letters? because else it might crash

Comment: I just did and it works. But i need to give the inputs separately like a enter, b enter, so on and so forth. I should have mentioned that in the questioner, that is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle the problem if you are only allowed to use an Array. One options is to take advantage of the internal character array of the string and perform case-insensitive lookups to ensure the entered character is valid. And again use the built-in character array of the string to only add unique characters to the final result.

```
static void Main()
{
    const string msg = "Only 5 letters between a and j are allowed.";
    const string letters = "abcdefghij";

    Console.WriteLine( "Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only:" );

    // read the entire input into a string
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // verify the input is the correct length.
    if( input == null || input.Length != 5 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( msg );
        return;
    }

    // store the final result w/o duplicates in a string
    string result = string.Empty;

    // we know there are 5 and only 5 characters in the input string,
    // so just iterate over the entire string.
    foreach( char c in input )
    {
        string value = c.ToString();

        // check if the character exists in the allowable characters using
        // a case insensitive lookup.
        if( letters.IndexOf( value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) < 0 )
        {
            // an invalid character was found, no need to continue.
            Console.WriteLine( value + " is inavlid." + msg );
            return;
        }

        // add the original character to the result string if it has yet to be added.
        if( !result.Contains( value ) )
        {
            result += value;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine( "You have entered the following inputs:" );
    Console.WriteLine( result );
}
```