# C# Need inputs in different lines

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that is will take letters as input only and not duplicated. I am getting error when i put one letter in an input. 
This is what i need to do, I need to get the user input in each line (like a enter, b enter, etc), if there is a duplication value i need a error message and continues with the input, and if there is incorrect value i get another error stating such. I cannot use LINQ, Hashset, nor list, it has to be arrays.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] Array = new char[5];
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only: ");
    string letters = "abcdefghij";

    char[] read = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray();

    //loop through array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (letters.Contains(read[i]) && !Array.Contains(read[i]))
        {
            Array[i] = read[i];
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: And your idea is to get the 5 letters in a row? One possible solution is to wrap the Console.ReadLine in a do while loop, and for each input from the user, you can loop trough his input to check for valid entry. if you loop for the 5 letters as for in loop for each char, and add them to a, let's say, hashset, that allows only unique values, by the end of each iteration the hashset should have 5 elements, if not, re issue the user to input a valid set of letters. after validation, you can step out of the loop and process the user input.

Comment: Actually Contains() is a Linq extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input with letters (a-z) only without special characters or numbers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191717/how-to-ask-for-user-input-with-letters-a-z-only-without-special-characters-or)

Comment: You've asked the same question 4 times in 2 days; please check the [StackOverflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on asking questions. [2 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191717), [1 day ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213210), [4 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239820), [1 hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241502)

Answer (score 0):

I think this more or less does what you want:

```
var max = 5;
var array = new char[max];
var letters = "abcdefghij";

var count = 0;
while (count < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter {0} Letters B/W a through j only: ", max);

    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    var read = key.KeyChar

    if (!letters.Contains(read))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
        continue;
    }

    var found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == read)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an duplicate value");
        continue;
    }

    array[count++] = read;
}

Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to enter the values individually then you would need to request each character in a loop.
Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string validValues = "abcdefghij";
    var enteredCharacters = new char[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < enteredCharacters.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a unique character between a and j");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a value.");
            return;
        }
        if (input.Length > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered more than 1 character");
            return;
        }
        var character = input[0];
        if (!validValues.Contains(character))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid character");
            return;
        }
        if (enteredValues.Contains(character))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have already entered this character");
            return;
        }
        enteredCharacters[i] = character;
    }
    // process numbers.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is you problem

**for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)**

this is your fix:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                char[] Array = new char[5];
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 5 Letters B/W a through j only: ");
                string letters = "abcdefghij";

                char[] read = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray();

                //loop through array
                for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (letters.Contains(read[i]) && !Array.Contains(read[i]))
                    {
                        Array[i] = read[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
                    }

                }

                Console.WriteLine("You have Entered the following Inputs: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```