# How to find out if the last and second to last character of a string are in a certain string array

Tags: arrays, string, comparison

Ok so I’m trying to find out if the last 2 characters in a string are constants and I have already created a string array that has all the constants in the alphabet, how can I check to see if the last 2 characters are in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your workspace (cpp,java,js,...) but don't define an alphabet array !!!

there is a better way :

***Regular Expression***

see this:

[C# Regex: Checking for "a-z" and "A-Z"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017778/c-sharp-regex-checking-for-a-z-and-a-z)

**to check two characters :**

1. Slice two characters from end of your string
2. Check them using something like this : `/^[A-Za-z]{2}/`